# I need to remove labels with 0 value [LibreOffice Calc]

Tags: graph, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am creating a very basic dashboard in libreoffice Calc. Right now I am trying to create some piecharts and bar charts. I am facing similar problem with both this type of charts.

Piecharts: I have ALL the labels to the right of the chart, even if those labels have an actual value of 0. I want labels with 0 value not to be displayed.

Bar charts: Similar to Piecharts, I want the chart not to display those X values with 0.

I am using LibreOffice Calc 6.4.7.2

If anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the source data table

[image: Filter Data In Place]

If you want to see the entire data table, you can put the filtering result in another place and build a diagram based on this trimmed data.

[image: Filter To Another Place]